# Change ActionBar Spinner divider color

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have the following Spinner in my ActionBar:

[image]

The "MY SHOPPING LIST" item is disabled. As you can see, the dividers are black, even though my themes are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Apptheme.Widget</item>

  </style>

</resources>
```

And the styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Apptheme.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Apptheme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownNavActionbar.Apptheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNavActionbar.Apptheme" parent="DropDownListView.Apptheme">
        <item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I was suggested to use actionDropDownStyle, add a listDivider attribute with value @android:color/white, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles

```
<style name="DropDownListView.ActionBar.Apptheme" parent="@style/DropDownListView.Apptheme">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Apptheme.Widget.ActionBarSpinner">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.ActionBar.Apptheme</item>
</style>
```

And then enable it with:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_Apptheme_Widget_ActionBarSpinner);
Spinner navSpinner = new Spinner(themedContext);
navSpinner.setAdapter(new ActionBarSpinnerAdapter(themedContext, shoppingList));
navSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item #" + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
});
actionBar.setCustomView(navSpinner);
```

Adapter code if you want it:

```
private class ActionBarSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public static final int TYPE_CATEGORY = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_ITEM     = 1;
    public static final int MAX_TYPE      = 2;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> mData;


    public ActionBarSpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> data)
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if(convertView == null){
            final int layoutId;
            switch(type){
                case TYPE_CATEGORY: layoutId = android.R.layout.preference_category; break;
                case TYPE_ITEM:     layoutId = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;  break;
                default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad type: " + type);
            }
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView)convertView;
        textView.setText(mData.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public ShoppingListItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position).getName().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return MAX_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_CATEGORY);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mData.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note - that you only have to apply the theme changes for it to work. The Custom View is optional and you can use setListNavigationCallbacks() to provide an ActionBar Spinner. In Android Studio I extended "android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown" for my DropDown Theme